# Trying to convert python to javascript opencv.js

Tags: javascript, html, opencv

I'm trying to develop a javascript code using opencv.js, I have python code with the same requirement, I converted many lines but some are very hard to find, please guide me.

last 3 lines from python code unable to find for javascript opencv.js.

```
def find_marker(image):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 35, 125)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts) //these three line are unable to find for javascript.
    c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
return cv2.minAreaRect(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first line, the code is using the function in imutils python package. If you see the grab_contours method in imutils.convenience file located at https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/convenience.py, you can see how it is implemented.
This is very simple to implement as a one liner in js.

```js
cnts = (cnts.length == 2) ? cnts[0] : (cnts.length == 3) ? cnts[1] : cnts
```

In second line, max is the inbuilt function of python for iterating through an iterable and to find the maximum based on the key.
This same functionality can be achieved in js as follows

```js
c = cnts.reduce(function(max, cur) {
    // here key is the cv2.contourArea function,
    // we apply that on the cnts[i] and finds the cnts[i]
    // such that cv2.contourArea(cnts[i]) is maximum
    if(cv2.contourArea(max) < cv2.countourArea(cur)) {
        return cur
    } else {
        return max
    }
});
```

Now for the third line I assume cv2.minAreaRect function is present in the js version too. I'm not sure though. But hope the above code works for you. Thank you.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I'm getting some error 1.TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, and 2.TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined. how to overcome this.

Comment: Does your findCountours returned any valid data? Please validate that by console.logging. First error is caused if the cnts is undefined i.e. when findCountours returned no data. For the second error it may happend that cnts is not an array. This might happened because of no valid data returned from findCountours. Please validate the result of findCountours. If everything goes well a little debugging and modification of the code I provided will help you. Please share a fiddle if possible. So that I can look into how exactly the error may be arising.

Comment: Hi, that cnts from cv. findContours showing undefine

Comment: are you assigning the return result of cv.findCountours to cnts? If that's the case, that's not how to do it. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/daa/tutorial_js_contours_begin.html from this document I can see that, you've to pass a cv.MatVector as second argument, and also I can see from your edited version of the question that, in your js code, you're doing that correctly. So the results will by default stored in that MatVector variable, use that and replace cnts.length with cnts.size()